# same Template function for int and std::string

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to use same template function for performing operation on int and std::string, eg:

```
template<typename T>
T add(typename a, typename b)
{
   return (a+b);       // incase for int
   return a.append(b); // incase for std::string
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think `a+b` won't work for strings if a and b both are strings ?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it not work?

Comment: What you are trying to do is a different operation for int and string. For int you are trying to add two integers to produce a 3rd integer, but for the string you are trying to append one string to the other. i.e. not producing a third string, but mutating one of the input arguments. As others have stated, if you are happy to produce a third string you can just do `a + b` for both.

Answer (score 1):

[std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) supports the [operator+](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B).

> concatenates two strings or a string and a char

```
template<typemane T>
T add(typename a, typename b)
{
   return a + b;
}
```